# An operator on $H\times H$, with $H$ Hilbert

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $(H, \langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle_H)$ a Hilbert complex space and consider  $H\times H$ with the inner product
$$\langle (u,v),(z,w)\rangle_{H\times H}\ =\ \langle u,z\rangle_H + \langle v,w\rangle_H.$$
Let, $A\in\mathcal{L}(H,H)$ and define the operator $B:H\times H\rightarrow H\times H$ by
$$B((u,v))\ :=\ (iA(v),\ -iA^*(u)),\quad \forall\ (u,v)\in H\times H.$$
Show that $\|B\| = \|A\|$ and $B$ is self-adjoint.

---

I was working in that problem, and I have already proved that $B\in\mathcal{L}(H\times H, H\times H)$ and $\|B\| \leq \|A\|$, but I have had problems in order to prove that $\|B\| \geq \|A\|$, please I need hints. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are almost there. Just note that for every $\|v \|=1$, we have $\|(0,v)\|=1$ whence
$$
\|B\|\geq \|B(0,v)\|=\|iAv\|=\|Av\|.
$$
Taking the sup over $\|v\|=1$ yields $\|B\|\geq \|A\|$ as desired.

To prove that $B$ is self-adjoint 
$$
((u,v),B(u',v'))=(u,iAv')+(v,-iA^*u')=((iA)^*u,v')+((-iA^*)^*v,u')
$$
$$
=(-iA^*u,v')+(iAv,u')=(B(u,v),(u',v')).
$$

---

Here is an outline of how this would be done in Operator Algebras, using $2\times 2$ matrices over $B(H)$. It is indeed a fundamental fact that $B(H\times H)$ can be identified with $M_2(B(H))$. Note that $H\times H$ is most often denoted by $H\oplus H$. And note that the vectors of $H$ disappear from the argument.

We can identify $B$ with the following $2\times 2$ matrix 
$$
B= \pmatrix{0&iA\\-iA^*&0}
$$
with respect to the orthogonal decomposition $H\times H=H\times \{0\}\oplus \{0\}\times H$. Therefore
$$
B^*=\pmatrix{0&(-iA^*)^*\\(iA)^*&0}=B\quad\mbox{and}\quad B^*B=B^2=\pmatrix{AA^*&0\\0&A^*A}.
$$
So $B$ is self-adjoint. Now in general, for a block diagonal operator over an orthogonal decomposition, we have
$$
\Big\|\pmatrix{S&0\\0&T}\Big\|=\max \{\|S\|,\|T\|\}.
$$
Now recall the $C^*$-norm property of the operator norm of $B(H)$: $\|A^*A\|=\|AA^*\|=\|A\|^2$. Hence
$$
\|B\|^2=\|B^*B\|=\max\{\|AA^*\|,\|A^*A\|\}=\|A\|^2\quad\Rightarrow\quad \|B\|=\|A\|.
$$

Comment: @FASCH You're welcome. May I ask what class you are taking, if any, with all these operator theory questions. And what textbook are you using?

Comment: Sure, I am taking Functional Analysis and we use the professor's notes. My professor said, that many of questions in his notes are from himself, and he always say "this proof (or this question) you'll not find in any book".